# pip3 is looking for a wrong path when there are two pythons installed

Tags: pip, puppy-linux

I have puppy linux installed on a 32 bit machine.
I installed python 3.5 and Pip3 libraries via puppy package manager.
When I run pip3, I receive this error:

```
root# pip3
bash: /usr/bin/pip3: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how can I fix this issue? Seems like pip3 is looking for a wrong path.

More info:

- I don't have pip installed.
- I have two different versions of python installed where the default one is Python 2.6.4
- Python path

  `root# which python`

  `/usr/bin/python`

---

What I tried:

- according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31769149/5510001) answer I tried

  `root# head -n1 /usr/local/bin/pip`
  `head: cannot open '/usr/local/bin/pip' for reading: No such file or directory`

however as shown above, it ends in an error. Moreover there is no `/usr/local/opt` directory

---

**Conclusion**:

Seems like pip3 is looking for `/usr/bin/python3` while python is installed in `/usr/bin/python3.5`

Comment: The real fix is of course to complain to the maintainer of the Python3 package (as opposed to complaining on [unix.se]), but in the mean time adding a symlink `python3` -> `python3.5` will make your life easier.

Comment: I ran `ln -s python3 -> python3.5` with success. but still I get the same error when running `pip3`. Strange point is when I run `python3` the command is not known, however `python3.5` is running. Did I make any mistake?

Comment: To create the symlink I'm talking about: `cd /usr/bin && ln -s python3.5 python3`.  You might also need to restart the current terminal after that (`$PATH` is sometimes cached etc.).

Comment: tnx,,now it is working. If you are interested, answer this question with what is written in comment and I will accept it

Comment: It's a workaround for a broken package, not a solution. _shrug_.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ hash -r
```

If you execute a command to erase something like caching, you can safely use pip.
There is not time for hash command now, so do not investigate deeply.

Please note this memorable second time so as not to forget.